# Как получить доступ к runtime в питоне

Tags: python

Каким образом из одного питонящего скрипта можно получить доступ к объектам, которые были созданы и использованы в других скриптах, запущенных одновременно с первым.
То есть, они все запущены одни питонящим процессом.

Comment: a точно много скриптов надо?

Comment: Ну, допустим есть два скрипта. Один в который я могу добавлять код и в нем ка краз работаю - другой видоизменять не могу. Как раз к объектам второго скрипта и нужно получить доступ.

Comment: [Раз](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) и [два](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html).

Comment: возможно просто `import`

Comment: Import Из runtime? Немного другое нужно.

Comment: Пусть даже запущены одним процессом, выполняются они в разных (если речь не об импорте). У них нет общей среды выполнения.

Comment: нет, просто import того другой скрипта, и вызов из него функций